# Searching for elements in the list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a problem where I scraped the data from a website and took the data from the table and put it in a list of tuples.

Something like this: `a = [("RAM", "8GB"),("HDD", "2TB"),("SSD","1TB")]`

Now I want to get the value of the second element (or just the index and I can get it like that) by searching the first like when using the list.index() function.

I know I can use a for loop or use a dict and that would categorize everything but I'm interested is there some other way or an already existing function that deals with that.

Comment: Build in function also uses loop so there is nothing which will work in <O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't perform a search in a list without using a loop. Even the built-in functions such as `in` or `.index()` are, in fact, loops with O(n) time complexity. For example:

```
>>> a = [("RAM", "8GB"),("HDD", "2TB"),("SSD","1TB")]
>>> [v for k, v in a if k == "HDD"]
['2TB']
```

You could use a `dict` or a `set` to reduce that to O(1):

```
>>> dict(a)["HDD"]
'2TB'
```

Comment: I did it like that but I thought maybe there is some other way of doing it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Other than using dict on the list you can use next and a comprehension:

```
>>> next(v for k, v in a if k == "HDD")
'2TB'
```

This allows you to also supply a default value if the value is non-existent too.